# Return maximum and minimum index based on condtion

Tags: r, apply

I'm trying to write a function that will work rowise through a matrix and return two vectors which contain the column number (x) where the first and last instance of 1 is found. However there are some conditions. My real dataset is 7,042 rows and 841 columns.

1. If 1 is found in the last column, both vectors return ncols + 1
2. If 1 never occurs both vectors should == 1
3. If 1 occurs multiple times in the row, but is separated **only by NA**, return the max column number + 1
4. If 1 occurs multiple times in the row, but is separated **by any 0**, return the max and minimum column numbers + 1
5. If 1 occurs only once in the row, return the column number + 1

Using the example dataset below

```
structure(list(T1 = c(NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), T2 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), T3 = c(NA, 3L, 3L, 0L, 3L, NA, 
NA, 3L, 3L), T4 = c(NA, 4L, NA, 0L, 0L, NA, 4L, 0L, 4L), T5 = c(5L, 
5L, 5L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 5L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")


+----+----+----+----+----+
| T1 | T2 | T3 | T4 | T5 |
+----+----+----+----+----+
| NA | NA | NA | NA | 1  |
| NA | NA | 1  | 1  | 1  |
| NA | NA | 1  | NA | 1  |
| 1  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  |
| NA | NA | 1  | 0  | 0  |
| NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| NA | NA | NA | 1  | 0  |
| NA | NA | 1  | 0  | 1  |
| NA | NA | 1  | 1  | 0  |
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Vector 1 should be returning `c(6,6,6,2,4,1,5,6,5)`, whilst vector 2 should return `c(6,6,6,2,4,1,5,4,5)`

My first attempt is below, but this only returns the final position that 1 was found in each columns

```
pattern <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = nrow(df), ncol = 1)
for (k in 1:ncol(df)) {
  df[, k][df[, k] > 0] <- k
}
pattern[, 1] <- apply(df, 1, function(x) max(x, na.rm = TRUE)+1)
```

My second attempt looked like this

```
extInd <- function(x) {
  v1 <- max(which(x > 0)) + 1
  v2 <- min(which(x > 0)) + 1
  return(c(v1, v2))
}

apply(df, 1, extInd)
```

My biggest issue is that I'm not sure how to check whether the occurrences of 1 are separated by only NA or 0, and then change the return result based on which values are separating them.

Comment: For the 4th row, 1 occurs only single time in the 1st column, not clear about the condition there

Comment: For 4th row, we would return 2. Effectively returning the position of the first zero.

Comment: sorry about that, I added in the 5th condition.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have solved this after talking with a colleague. We can return the maximum column number +1 where 1 occurs, and the minimum column number of 0. If there are no 1's, return 1. If there are no zeros, return the value for the 1's.

```
structure(list(T1 = c(NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), T2 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), T3 = c(NA, 3L, 3L, 0L, 3L, NA, 
NA, 3L, 3L), T4 = c(NA, 4L, NA, 0L, 0L, NA, 4L, 0L, 4L), T5 = c(5L, 
5L, 5L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 5L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")

extInd <- function(x) {
  ## check where 1 occurs and return max(x)+1
  pos_1 <- max(which(x == 1), na.rm = TRUE) + 1
  ## if never, return 1
  if (is.infinite(pos_1)) {
    pos_1 <- 1
  }
  ## check where 0 occurs and return first instance
  pos_0 <- min(which(x == 0), na.rm = TRUE)
  ## if never 0, return pos_1
  if (is.infinite(pos_0)) {
    pos_0 <- pos_1
  }
  return(c(pos_1, pos_0))
}

suppressWarnings(t(apply(df, 1, extInd)))
```